# how to keep text selection after page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, timer, updatepanel

I have a text "Hello world" in a div which I want to get selected after update panel refresh, the selection goes off after the timer interval, how to keep text selection after page refresh for a certain interval.

```
    <i>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="sort-item">
                    Hello world
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
    </form>
</i>
```

Comment: Store it into browser's localstorage and after refresh get the data back and put the selection highlighted back to the text.

Comment: thank you @HimanshuUpadhyay can you please give me some code reference or any like

Comment: how do you get it selected? Setting up background color for the div "sort-item" ?

Comment: no background colour will be there, in case of selection. If we double click on any text then the default selection will be blue, but after the timer event fires that selection goes off. we want to keep selection remain persist after refresh. @HimanshuUpadhyay

Answer (score 0):

use html localstorage:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var id = $("#sort-item").text();
if(localStorage.getItem("sort-item-id") == ""){
  localStorage.setItem("sort-item-id", id);
}else{
$("#sort-item").text(localStorage.getItem("sort-item-id"));
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you @deepak singh but selected text goes off after refresh.

Comment: Just do : console.log(localStorage.getItem("sort-item-id")); and see the console.